# (Expo) React Native not updating state after fetching data from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am creating an app in react-native. I encounter with an issue in app. I am fetching data from server and updating my state with fetched data. Data from server are console logging without any error. However after setting state, react-native is not re-rendering my questions on screen. But When i save my project from code editor, and expo reloads, the data (questions) are visible on screen. I can't find solution or from where error is occuring. Hope down below code and gif demonstrate my problem.


I Have remove some styling from code to reduce length but code is still long. Link to original file (code) can be find here [link to code](https://github.com/Ferin79/Online-Exam-MERN/blob/master/app/screens/Profile/Solution.js)


[image: Error Image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MultipleChoice from "react-native-multiple-choice-picker";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  (other imports),
  Button,
} from "react-native";
import LoadingScreen from "../Loading";
import firebase from "../../config/firebase";
import SERVER from "../../config/variable";

const Solution = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [questionData, setQuestionData] = useState([]);
  const [correctAnswer, setCorrectAnswer] = useState([]);
  const [wrongAnswer, setWrongAnswer] = useState([]);
  const [notAttempted, setNotAttempted] = useState([]);
  const [questionCount, setQuestionCount] = useState(0);
  const [allQuestion, setAllQuestion] = useState([]);
  const { examid } = route.params;

  const fetchSolution = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${SERVER}admin/get/result-for-user`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "Application/json",
          "Content-Type": "Application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
          examid,
        }),
      });
      const responseData = await response.json();
      setQuestionData(responseData.data);
      setCorrectAnswer(await JSON.parse(responseData.result[0].correctAnsArr));
      const data1 = JSON.parse(responseData.result[0].wrongAnsArr);
      setWrongAnswer(data1);
      setNotAttempted(await JSON.parse(responseData.result[0].notAttemtedArr));
      const datafinal = await updateQuestion();
      setAllQuestion(datafinal);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      Alert.alert("Server Error");
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const updateQuestion = () => {
    var correctAnsArr = [];
    var wrongAnsArr = [];
    var notAttemtedArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < correctAnswer.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < questionData.length; j++) {
        if (correctAnswer[i].questionId === questionData[j].id) {
          questionData[j].selectedOption = correctAnswer[i].selectedOption;
          correctAnsArr.push(questionData[j]);
        }
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < wrongAnswer.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < questionData.length; j++) {
        if (wrongAnswer[i].questionId === questionData[j].id) {
          questionData[j].selectedOption = wrongAnswer[i].selectedOption;
          wrongAnsArr.push(questionData[j]);
        }
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < notAttempted.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < questionData.length; j++) {
        if (notAttempted[i].questionId === questionData[j].id) {
          questionData[j].selectedOption = notAttempted[i].selectedOption;
          notAttemtedArr.push(questionData[j]);
        }
      }
    }

    return [...correctAnsArr, ...wrongAnsArr, ...notAttemtedArr];
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSolution();
  }, []);

  const RenderQuestion = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          {allQuestion.length > 0 ? (
            <View
              key={allQuestion[0].id}
              style={{
                width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
                  Question {questionCount + 1} of {allQuestion.length}
                </Text>
              </View>

              {allQuestion[questionCount].isQuestionImage === "1" ? (
                <View
                  style={{
                    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
                    display: "flex",
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  <Image
                    style={{
                      height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.5,
                      width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.8,
                    }}
                    source={{
                      uri: allQuestion[questionCount].questionFile,
                    }}
                  />
                </View>
              ) : (
                <View>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 35, margin: 15 }}>
                    {allQuestion[questionCount].questionText}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              )}
              <RenderOption />
            </View>
          ) : (
            <View>
              <Text>No Data</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const RenderOption = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        {allQuestion.length > 0 ? (
          <View>
            {allQuestion[questionCount].isOptionImage === "1" ? (
              <MultipleChoice
                direction={"column"}
                chosenIndex={allQuestion[questionCount].selectedOption}
                choices={[
                  <Image
                    style={{
                      height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.3,
                      width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.6,
                    }}
                    source={{
                      uri: allQuestion[questionCount].optionAFile,
                    }}
                  />,
                  <Image
                    style={{
                      height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.3,
                      width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.6,
                    }}
                    source={{
                      uri: allQuestion[questionCount].optionBFile,
                    }}
                  />,

                  <Image
                    style={{
                      height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.3,
                      width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.6,
                    }}
                    source={{
                      uri: allQuestion[questionCount].optionCFile,
                    }}
                  />,
                  <Image
                    style={{
                      height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.3,
                      width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.6,
                    }}
                    source={{
                      uri: allQuestion[questionCount].optionDFile,
                    }}
                  />,
                ]}
              />
            ) : (
              <MultipleChoice
                direction={"column"}
                chosenIndex={allQuestion[questionCount].selectedOption}
                choices={[
                  <Text>
                    {allQuestion[questionCount].optionAText}
                  </Text>,
                  <Text>
                    {allQuestion[questionCount].optionBText}
                  </Text>,
                  <Text>
                    {allQuestion[questionCount].optionCText}
                  </Text>,
                  <Text>
                    {allQuestion[questionCount].optionDText}
                  </Text>,
                ]}
              />
            )}
          </View>
        ) : (
          <View></View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };
  const Renderbutton = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        {questionCount != 0 ? (
          <View>
            <Button
              color="#f9a602"
              title="Prev"
              onPress={() => {
                setQuestionCount(() => questionCount - 1);
              }}
            />
          </View>
        ) : null}
        {questionCount + 1 < allQuestion.length ? (
          <View>
            <Button
              title="Next"
              onPress={() => {
                setQuestionCount(() => questionCount + 1);
              }}
            />
          </View>
        ) : null}

        <View>
          <Button
            color="red"
            title="Finish"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ResultList")}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingScreen />;
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ display: "flex", flex: 1 }}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("../../images/signup_screen.jpg")}
        style={{ flex: 1, resizeMode: "cover" }}
      >
        <View>
          <ScrollView>
            <RenderQuestion />
            <Renderbutton />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Solution;
```

Comment: just to be clear, the issue is after `useEffect` run on the first render, response setting new state but component not re-render?

Comment: Yes thats the problem. How do i fix it ?

Comment: can you console log of `datafinal ` right before `setAllQuestion(datafinal);`? also, `setState` is async call, doing something like `setIsLoading(true);` and `setIsLoading(false)` at same function its really tricky

Comment: console log of datafinal is returning empty array.   However i have used await for on const dataFinal = await updateQuestion();

Comment: How to fix this async code issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `updateQuestion()` function, what will be populate as `allQuestion`, you expect `correctAnswer, questionData, ...` states, to hold the data they got in `fetchSolution()`.

The thing is, that `setState` functions are async calls, and while you get into `updateQuestion()`, from inside `fetchSolution()`, the state isn't what you expect it to be.

Adding an example of how use `useEffect` for waiting changes affect state and only then action will be fired

---

```
  const Solution = ({ route, navigation }) => {
     const [questionData, setQuestionData] = useState([]);
     const [correctAnswer, setCorrectAnswer] = useState([]);
     const [allQuestion, setAllQuestion] = useState([]);

       const fetchSolution = async () => {
             setQuestionData(['something'])
             setCorrectAnswer(['something'])
           }

        useEffect(() => fetchSolution(), []);
        useEffect(() => correctAnswer.length && questionData.length && 
                         updateQuestion(), [correctAnswer, questionData]);
```

Comment: This code run into error saying " An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.%s%s,  You returned 0 " and " destroy is not a function. (In 'destroy()', 'destroy' is 0)" and also " Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function, "

Comment: You can clone the repo and try to solve the problem in your device.  database is hosted online, so no problem for data. as the problem is solve, you can contribute to my code.  Thanks for help.